# Obtaining Facebook Page Access Token in Facebook iOS SDK 3.5.x

Tags: facebook-ios-sdk

I have a Facebook Page which I'm the Admin. I have logged in Facebook & obtained a `FBSession.actionSession`. i.e. `isOpen = YES`

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"access_token",  @"fields",
                                   nil];
    FBRequest *req = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:myPageID parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [req startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
        });
    }];
```

But I got `nil` in `result`. I know I have to add `manage_pages` permission, but where to add it ?

Note: I'm using Facebook SDK 3.5.3

Additional Information from debugging logging:

```
2013-06-27 12:18:34.722 TestFBPostPage[13224:19a03] FBSDKLog: Request <#1113>:
  URL:  https://graph.facebook.com/MY_PAGE_ID?sdk=ios&fields=access_token&migration_bundle=fbsdk%3A20130409&format=json&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED
  Method:   POST
  UserAgent:    FBiOSSDK.3.5.3
  MIME: multipart/form-data; boundary=3i2ndDfv2rTHiSisAbouNdArYfORhtTPEefj3q2f
  Attachments:  
    sdk:    ios
    fields: access_token
    migration_bundle:   fbsdk:20130409
    format: json
    access_token:   ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED

2013-06-27 12:18:34.952 TestFBPostPage[13224:19a03] FBSDKLog: Error: HTTP status code: 403
2013-06-27 12:18:34.954 TestFBPostPage[13224:19a03] FBSDKLog: Response <#1113> <Error>:
The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)
```

Comment: I also got this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is SDK 4.x, but here's what I've gotten to get it to work

```
 __block NSString *pageToken;
        FBSDKGraphRequest *newRequest = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/accounts", [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].userID] parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
        [newRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

            if (error) {
                NSLog([error localizedDescription]);
            }else{
               //here you made need to do some debugging. not sure how it works with multiple pages
                pageToken = [[[result objectForKey:@"data"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"access_token"];


        }];
```

Again, not entirely sure how it works when a user is the admin of multiple pages but, but for single page admins, this is what I got to work